# Enum : Difference between using enum and class with static variables

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, enums, static-variables

I have a small question with using `enum` and using a `java class` and defining `static variables`.

For example we can define enum like :-

```
public enum RequestCodeEnum {

    TRANSACTION(1), REPORTS(2), BUDGET(3), CATEGORY(4), CURRENCY(5);

    private int value;

    private RequestCodeEnum(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getCode(){
        return value;
    }

}
```

And for the same thing, we can use a java class with static variables like :-

```
public class ActivityRequestCode {

    public static int TRANSACTION_CODE  = 1;
    public static int REPORTS           = 2;
    public static int BUDGET            = 3;
    public static int CATEGORY          = 4;
    public static int CURRENCY          = 5;

}
```

And for calling both the classes we can do :-

```
int i = RequestCodeEnum.CATEGORY.getCode();
int j = ActivityRequestCode.TRANSACTION_CODE;
```

I want to know what difference it will make or are those the alternative solutions to one another. 7

Thank you.

Comment: If you want a generic answer check the answers of the other question, but If you want an answer specific to android, please rewrite your question to clearly mention it

Comment: @T.J. I think it's probably a dup somewhere but the marked one is too general for this instance.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: Perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252465/android-enum-vs-static-final-ints

Comment: Please check out this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hzs6OBcvNQE and use @IntDef or equivalent -> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/IntDef.html

Comment: @T.J. I like it better because it's android specific.

Comment: I am not talking specifically about any programming language. Just the code design pattern

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that the constants are preferred on Android as they consume less memory.

> Enums often require more than twice as much memory as static
>   constants. You should strictly avoid using enums on Android.

See https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory.html

Comment: I would also read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29183904/should-i-strictly-avoid-using-enums-on-android

Comment: Thank you both for the answer. Now I have a clear idea about when to use `enums`.