# How much memory does an enum take?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, types, enums

I need to decide if I will use `enum`s in a big array I need in my project. To do that I have to know what is size of an `enum` variable.

```
enum Player 
{ 
     First, 
     Second, 
     Third, 
     Fourth 
};

private Player _owner;
```

How much memory will `_owner` take?

I haven't found proper information about this in C#, that's why this C++ and Java topic does not apply: [How much memory do Enums take?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143285/how-much-memory-do-enums-take)

Comment: I can't say definitively, but I *believe* you're looking at 128 bytes based on what the 4 integers take up in the `enum`.

Comment: It depends on the underlying type.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`Enum` values are converted to values of the underlying type at compile time. Therefore, a variable of an enumeration type itself based on `int` type (which is the default) **doesn't use any more memory** than any other `int` variable in your code.

An `Enum` underlying structure can be any of the following:

- `byte`
- `sbyte`
- `short`
- `ushort`
- `int`
- `uint`
- `long`
- `ulong`

Since your `Player` enumeration type does not specify the underlying time, the compiler will see it as an `int`-based `Enum`. If memory is a concern, you may want to consider declaring it as derived from `byte` instead:

```
enum Player : byte
{ 
    First, 
    Second, 
    Third, 
    Fourth 
};
```

**Be careful though:** a newly declared `Enum` variable will have the same value as it's underlying type's default value, which will always be zero. In an enum with unspecified literal values, the first item in the list is assumed as the default value. In your case, that would be `First`:

```
private Player _owner; // this value will initially equals Player.First
```

You may want to insert an additional `Player` literal labelled `None`, `Empty` or `Undefined` to represent a `Player` variable default value:

```
enum Player : byte
{ 
    Undefined = 0;
    First, 
    Second, 
    Third, 
    Fourth 
};

private Player _owner; // this value will initially equals Player.Undefined
```

Of course, if you are okay having `First` as the default value, you may leave it as is. Be aware though that not having a dedicated default `Enum` value is often considered a bad coding practice.

As an alternative, since any `Enum` are structure-based, you may also declare your `_owner` variable as `Player?` so that it will instead be `null` by default:

```
private Player? _owner; // this value will initially equals null
```

To sum it up, simply remember that `Enum` literals simply acts as constants for their underlying type. Their purpose is to make code easier to read and to enforce a limited set of possible values at compile time.

For more information, look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx).

Comment: Perhaps more important is that they're not using any less memory than those. As you correctly say, `Player`'s underlying type is `int`, and it can hold any value `int` can, but programmers familiar with other languages might expect it to take up a single byte.

Comment: @hvd So there is no possiblity of `enum` taking only one byte?

Comment: @Michał That's possible, but requires explicitly specifying a one-byte underlying type (`byte` or `sbyte`).

Comment: Every enumeration type has an underlying type, which can be any integral type except char.