# How To Declare Constants in Android without using public static final

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, bluetooth

I am developing a Bluetooth app that is always running until user uninstalls app or switches off their mobile. I am getting an error message: "unfortunately app stopped working". From my initial research this appears to be a memory leak issue. So far I have found out that any object with static reference will leak memory. So I need to remove static references of variables. My project has many constants, how can I write constants without using public static final?

currently, i am using something like this:
`public  static final int NOTIFICATION_ID=1234;`

**Update**

I think My question needs some more info so here it is

private static variable problem
 1) Hi Friends,My app uses database has 9 tables each table has 7 to 13 columns,So the column name I am declaring like 
    private static final String COLUMN_NAME_ACTIVE = "active";
similarly more than 70 static variables has been declared.
2)some of the instances to access in another class i have declared
3)1 util class it is a static class

Comment: use interface instead defining in class

Comment: static final constants are not your problem here. They take up some memory, but it's all allocated at startup and never move afterward. You might have a more complex problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470651/creating-a-memory-leak-with-java

Comment: "currently i am using like public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID=1234;" -- that is not a memory leak. "When I searched I came to know this is memory leak issue" -- you do not crash from a memory leak, unless you are getting an `OutOfMemoryError`.

Answer (score 1):

You can define constants in res/values under xml format and refer to it using `R.` In this case `R.integer.`.

**Example:**

```
<resources>
    <integer name="notif_id">1234</integer>
</resources>
```

**Example usage:**

`someMethodName(R.integer.notif_id)`

Comment: `R.id`  is just a generated interface full of static final variables.

Comment: My bad. I didn't realize. I guess this thread might as well be "different ways of making static final variables without using the words 'static' and 'final'" with the number of actually static final answers that are here.

Comment: That's what it is right now indeed. Because, anyway, static final is the only viable way to store these constants.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Interface class and define variables there

```
public interface Constants{

String Name="AAA";
String Age="20";

}
```

And use it like this

```
String name=Constants.Name;
```

Comment: He can directly use interface variable no need of String name=Constants.Name;

Comment: Yes but i was just trying to explain

Comment: Variables in an interface are static final (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430756/why-are-interface-variables-static-and-final-by-default)

Comment: I dint know this thanks for info ,but i need 1 clarification is this creates memory issue?

Answer (score 0):

you need to persist data, you can use `SharedPreferences` like this :

Decalre your `SharedPreferences`:

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

write to your SharedPreferences :

```
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("key", "value");
editor.commit();
```

and read from it when you want :

```
String value = sharedpreferences.getString("key","defaultValue");
```

Comment: But then he will have to initialize it, which means he will need a bunch of constants/litteral somewhere anyway. And it will make accessing the constants difficult because it will require a context and more than a single line.

Comment: he needs only to save the value of the `NOTIFICATION_ID`

Comment: He gave one exemple, does not mean he have a single constant in his whole app

Comment: maybe but he doesn't specify what he needs exactly

Comment: Even if he only need one value, he would still need another constant to store the key anyway.

Comment: Values in `SharedPreferences`  are indexed by a key. So he needs to have the key to access the value he stored.

Comment: take the notification_id example save the value and get it when you need it by the key of notification_id

Comment: so your key is "notification_id" which IS a constant by itself if you need to pass it to the SharedPreferences

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149233/discussion-between-oussema-aroua-and-litelite).

Answer (score 0):

Usually I declare constants in a single file, that will help me and other developers to update any configuration/value.

You can achieve same by using `interface`. Interfaces are static final by default and variable declarations that are declared to be both static and final.

```
public interface MyConstants {
  String SERVER_URL = "my_server_address";
  int SPLASH_LAUNCH_TIME = 1000;
}
```

You can use constants in Interfaces by 2 ways -

a. Either call them directly, like MyConstants.SERVER_URL;

b. Implement that `interface` in your class and access all constants directly.

Choose your approach wisely, by using approach 2 you will flood all constants in your class. Even they are not required in that class.

Comment: You should mention that "variables" in interfaces are `static final` *implicitly*, even if not being declares so, which is what the OP wanted to avoid...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle thank you for pointing that, updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Enum:

```
public enum Gender {
   MALE,
   FEMALE
}
```

And access it like this:

```
Gender.MALE
```

Comment: It seems that in java an enum just generate a class with a bunch of static final inside. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143285/how-much-memory-do-enums-take